# How to create a Pull Request using github3.py API?

Tags: python, github, github-api, github3.py

This seems to be supported in the [github web api](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request), but I found no example in the docs and it doesn't seem to have been implemented in the API.

Am I missing something? Is it possible to create a PR through github3 python API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant method is *Repository.create_pull*:

http://github3py.readthedocs.org/en/master/repos.html#github3.repos.repo.Repository.create_pull

To use it, get a Repository instance of the repo you're interested in, then call 'create_pull' with the ref of the head of the pull request.